# How can I confirm the range of unsigned long integer in C?

Tags: c, gcc, integer, range, literals

**unsigned long** has 8 bytes on my Linux gcc.

**unsigned long long** has 8 bytes on my Linux gcc, too.

So I think the range of integers they can show is from **0 min** to **(2^64 - 1)max**.

Now I want to confirm if I'm correct.

Here is my **code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("long takes up %d bytes:\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("long long takes up %d bytes:\n", sizeof(long long));

    unsigned long a = 18446744073709551615;
    a++;
    printf("a + 1 = %lu\n", a); 

    unsigned long long b = 18446744073709551615;
    b++;
    printf("b + 1 = %llu\n", b); 

    return 0;
}
```

However, the code cannot be compiled and I get the following warning:

```
warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned
```

Where did I do wrong? How can I modify the code ?

Comment: Sidenote: `sizeof` returns `size_t`, so format specifier `%d` is invalid. Use `%zu` instead.

Comment: interstingly you test nothing with this code.... You will ALWAYS get `0` independent of the size of the variable.

Comment: @KamiKaze With a 16-byte `unsigned long long`, `printf("%llu\n", b);` will nicely print "18446744073709551616".  ALWAYS is a long time, just wait a decade for 128-bit `unsigned long long.

Comment: @chux well played. I should have said for all datatypes up to 64bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you initialize num, you can append the **"UL"** for `unsigned long` and **ULL** for `unsigned long long`.

For example:

```
unsigned long a = 18446744073709551615UL;
unsigned long long b = 18446744073709551615ULL;
```

Also, use `%zu` instead of `%d` because sizeof return `size_t`.

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant):

> - integer-suffix, if provided, may contain one or both of the following (if both are provided, they may appear in any order:
>
>   - `unsigned-suffix` (the character `u` or the character `U`)
>   - `long-suffix` (the
>       character `l` or the character `L`) or the `long-long-suffix` (the character
>       sequence `ll` or the character sequence `LL`) (since C99)

**[C standard 5.2.4.2.1](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>` :**

> **1** The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for
>   `CHAR_BIT` and `MB_LEN_MAX`, the following shall be replaced by
>   expressions that have the same type as would an expression that is an
>   object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
>   promotions. **Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or
>   greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same
>   sign.**

Comment: The `L` and `LL` are not needed.  It is only the `U` that is need to quiet the warning.

Answer (score 4):

Initialize unsigned numbers with -1. This will automatically be MAX value in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("long takes up %d bytes:\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("long long takes up %d bytes:\n", sizeof(long long));

    unsigned long a = -1;
    printf("a = %lu\n", a); 

    unsigned long long b = -1;
    printf("b = %llu\n", b); 

    return 0;
}
```

**Update**: Changed the code based on comments :)

Comment: Well this is true but I don't think this answers the question of OP.

Comment: @KamiKaze This post does directly answer the title question: "How can I confirm the range of unsigned long integer in C?"

Comment: @chux The only thing mentioned and changed in this answer (in contrast to the question) is that (2^64 - 1) was replaced with -1. Then it adds 1 et voila the result is 0. This is does not tell us anything about the range of unsigned long.

Comment: @KamiKaze True about the `printf()` does not convey the range with a zero output.

Answer (score 4):

You find some useful definitions in `<limits.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I confirm the range of unsigned long integer in C?

**Best**, just use the macros from `<limits.h>`.  It better self documents code's intent.

```
unsigned long long b_max = ULLONG_MAX;
```

Alternatively, assign -1 to the *unsigned* type.  As -1 is not in the range of an *unsigned* type, it will get converted to the target type by adding the MAX value of that type plus 1.  The works even on rare machines that have padding.

> ... if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.  C11dr §6.3.1.3 2

The min values is of course 0 for an *unsigned* type.

```
unsigned long long b_min = 0;
unsigned long long b_max = -1;
printf("unsigned long long range [%llu %llu]\n", b_min, b_max);
```

Note that picky compilers will complain about assigning an out-of-range value with `b_max = -1;`.   Use `ULLONG_MAX`.

---

> Where did I do wrong?

The warning "warning: integer constant is so large that it is unsigned" is due to `18446744073709551615` is a integer decimal constant outside the `long long` range on your platform. Unadorned decimal constants are limited to that.  Append a `U` or `u`.  Then the compiler will consider `unsigned long long`.

```
unsigned long long b = 18446744073709551615u;
```

Further, there is no C spec that says 18446744073709551615 is the max value of `unsigned long long`.  It must be at *least* that.  It could be larger.  So assigning `b = 18446744073709551615u` may not assign the *max* value.

> How can I modify the code ?

Shown above

Answer (score 0):

As rsp stated you can specify the type of the literal with `UL` and `ULL`.
But this won't lead to a conclusive result in your code for the arithmetics.

The value your print will always be `0` because

```
2^64 % 64 = 0 // 64 = 8 byte
2^64 % 32 = 0 // 32 = 4 byte
2^64 % 16 = 0 // 16 = 2 byte
```

as you can see the variable size always doubles so if you us a wrapping number for 8 bytes it just wraps multiple types on the smaller sizes and yields the same result.

The `sizeof` will show you the right values.

But generally you want to check for these things in code and not on output so you could use `limits.h` as suggested by Arndt Jonasson.

or you can use `static_assert` to check at compile time.